# Using purrr to plot multiple items against each other

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I am trying to learn `purrr` from the `tidyverse`
I have set up a piece of code to attempt to plot all variables in the iris data-set against each other to see if they are linearly related. Unfortunately I don't seem to get anything back except blank plots. Below is my example. Can anyone help

```
library(tidyverse)

mydf <- iris %>% 
  as_tibble %>% 
  dplyr::select(everything(), -Species)

# Create a grid of names of columns
mynames <- names(mydf)  
mygrid <- expand.grid(x=mynames, y =mynames) 

# Define function 
plot_my_data <- function(mydata, x, y){
  ggplot(mydata, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_smooth()}

map2(.x = mygrid$x,
     .y = mygrid$y,
     .f = ~ plot_my_data(mydf, .x,.y))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 issues in your code.

First one is that you use `aes` where you should use `aes_string`, and second is that you have factors and not characters in mygrid.

This works:

```
mygrid <- expand.grid(x=mynames, y =mynames,stringsAsFactors = F) 

# Define function 
plot_my_data <- function(mydata, x, y){
  ggplot(mydata, aes_string(x, y)) +
    geom_smooth()}

map2(.x = mygrid$x,
     .y = mygrid$y,
     .f = ~ plot_my_data(mydf, .x,.y))
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Moody_Mudskipper. Can you tell me why aes_string matters?

Comment: when using just `aes` you're implying that the column names are `x` and `y` while they are the values of these variables, so your arguments are `strings`, not `names`, so you use `aes_string`